# Current path and inputting files

Tags: java, file-io, command-line

I'm writing a fairly simple Java program, and some options I require from the user give them the ability to read from a list of text for data comparisons.

What I would like to do is to give them the ability to simply define the file if it is in the current working path, and assume so unless they provide a separate path to their file. I'd like to use the same approach to generate a output file wherever they define.

So I start by checking if the file even exists (which does not work if you do not define a full path):

```
File f1 = new File(inputFile);
        if(f1.exists())
            System.out.println("Exists");
        else if(!f1.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot find file " + inputFile);
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

So I could create the file with `new File(path/inputFile)`, but I can break that fairly easily.

I want them to be able to do any of the following:

```
program.exe -m -1 inputFile.txt outputFile.txt

program.exe -m -1 C:\Users\tmp\Desktop\inputFile.txt outputFile.txt

program.exe -m -1 inputFile.txt C:\outputFile.txt
```

Any suggestions on where I might make my next step?

Comment: are you using String[] args in the main function?

Comment: Relative file paths are relative to the current working directory so this already does what you want doesn't it?

Comment: @jaesanx, I'm using Getopts/Longopts (GNU ported) to parse all of the args. So I'm passing that string to my function to check that the file exists, using the string as the path input to create the File object. I know I get the correct name and that the file exists, however it only works provided the entire path.

Comment: @Joni, no the problem seems to be the way that I'm passing my filename. Passing the entire path to it works, while passing the filename does not. I am running the program in the same directory as well, and I thought it would automatically assume the current working directory as it should.

Comment: So what does the program use to resolve relative paths? You can find out by getting the absolute path from the file object.

Comment: @Joni, My absolute path is being defined as my workspace directory, even though I'm running the binary itself in a separate directory. Definitely need to fix that.

Comment: I noticed you are executing the program as "program.exe." That's not normal for java applications. How did you generate this .exe?

Comment: I'm not actually. That is just an example of how I want to run it for the users who will use it. Right now it's just a .jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like

```
String currentUserPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

to get the current path from where the application is being ran. Then you can check if the user provided on args[0] a full path, something like:

```
String inputPath = args[0];
inputPath = inputPath.trim().toLowerCase(); // as you are using windows case doesn't matter    
if (!inputPath.startsWith("c:"))
    inputPath = currentUserPath + inputPath;
```

and you could do something similar for the outputFile